# Azure DataFactory in GCP

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I need to synchronize multiple "on premise" Microsoft SQL server databases from business datacenters to cloud storage (let's call it blob storage).

In the past, I've used the Azure Data Factory on-premise client to bypass firewall considerations, not require a VPN, and delivery data directly to Azure Blob storage.

I need to do the same thing using Google tools (destination Google Cloud Storage). Is there an equivalent GCP tool that does not require a VPN? If not, any lowish-priced tool recommendations?

Comment: To emulate the ADF workaround, you need a process running on-premises that can connect out to a cloud store. So that would be the first GCP requirement - a service that installs on premises. Failing that, there are any number of scripted or code base solutions that can read from SQL Server and write to GCP storage. These would be custom builds but if you are just copying complete tables it shouldn't be too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

To send file from on prem to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) your need 2 things

- [gcloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) installed on your local environment
- a [service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys). *Keep it secrets!!*

Then, follow these steps

- Authenticate your [service account in gcloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) `gcloud auth activate-service-account <Service Account email> --key-file=<Service Account File>`
- Extract your data locally
- Use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to send the file to the cloud

The connexion is authenticated and don't required VPN.